# Регулярное выражение в Hive, ошибка "Error while compiling statement: FAILED..."

Tags: регулярные-выражения, hive

Всем привет

Вот пример моего текста  `Тест kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj7. 87sf8sf`. Я хочу, чтобы моё регулярное выражение выдавало мне `s.test.ru/g/dskj7`.

Здесь `kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf` получаем `s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf` Здесь `kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj78. 7sf8sf` получаем `s.test.ru/g/dskj78` Здесь `kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf test` получаем `s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf`

На тренажёре регулярных выражений удалось получить несколько работающих вариантов:
`<=kssc:\\/\\/)(?:(?!\\.?\\s).)*`
`(kssc:\/\/)((?:(?!\.?\s).)*)`
`(?<=kssc:\/\/)(?:(?!\.\s).)*`
`(?<=kssc:\/\/)(?:(?!\.?\s).)*`

Все они не работают в Hive, за исключением `(kssc:\/\/)((?:(?!\.?\s).)*)` Это возвращает `kssc://`
Ошибка такая:
`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: line 598:4 Wrong arguments ''<=kssc:\\/\\/)(?:(?!\\.?\\s).)*''...`

Подскажите советом!

Comment: `(?:kssc:\/\/)((?:(?!\.?\s).)*)`?

Comment: @dIm0n с ошибкой не падает, но ничего не возвращает